# Bind text files MySQL and create identifier

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I have 1,000 text (.txt) files named data.001, data.002, data.003, and so on. I want to create an SQL database with one table that contains all data.xxx files row-binded (using MySQL in Linux). When binding the rows I need to have a new column which identifies from which table the data is from.

Therefore, I'd appreciate some help in how I can efficiently implement this in Maria DB (MySQL Linux). I have tried several ways of using loops but I have not managed so far.

Comment: Maridb cannot read txt files so you must be using some other tech to loop , what is it?

Comment: @P.Salmon ??? [LOAD_FILE() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load_file/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 (Debian 10), and I'm able to open the delimited .txt file on this.